# Difference between net.core.rmem_max and net.ipv4.tcp_rmem

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp, linux-kernel

What's the difference between net.core.rmem_max and the third value of net.ipv4.tcp_rmem? Which has the higher priority for tcp connections?

For below two examples, what's the max buffer for tcp connections?

```
Case 1:
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=7388608
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='4096 87380 8388608'

Case 2:
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='4096 87380 7388608'
```

Comment: Priority related to tcp?

Comment: @Nils Yes, for tcp connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Core is the overall max receive buffer, while tcp relates to just that protocol.

As for the priority-question:
It seems that the tcp-setting will take precendence over the common max setting, which is a bit confusing. Setting max has no effect on the current tcp setting (just tested on CentOS 5).

A more correct description would have been: **default_max** - but that was propably too longish.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but this conflicts with what `man tcp` says about `tcp_rmem`'s max value: `the maximum size of the receive buffer used by each TCP socket. This value does not override the global net.core.rmem_max` - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546835/tcp-receiving-window-size-higher-than-net-core-rmem-max. Is `man tcp` wrong?

Comment: @nh2 That would not be the first time where a man page is wrong.

Comment: How exactly did you test it?

Comment: @Wildcard I set the value and read the other value after Settings the first

Comment: @Nils, simply reading the values won't tell you if one overrides another -- you have to actually try to get a TCP buffer which exceeds the net.core.[wmem/rmem]_max buffer in order to test out such overriding.

Comment: I've reported the apparent man page bug here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209327